# NoRegionError: You must specify a region. error writing to dynamodb

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am writing my Dataframe to dynamodb using aws wrangler in jupytr notebook and the code throws the `"NoRegionError: You must specify a region."`.

How can this be resolved?

```py
import awswrangler as wr

from pathlib import Path

session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id='*****', aws_secret_access_key='**********')

dynamodb=session.resource('dynamodb',region_name='ca-central-1')

wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information")
```

Comment: try `wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information", boto3_session=session)` - IDK if it should be necessary: https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.dynamodb.put_df.html EDIT: `wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information", boto3_session=dynamodb)`? - should be the first...

Comment: @Shmack Tried that already. Getting the same "specify the region ' error

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your db is available in that zone? You might need to check the VPC it created and make sure that it is configured to support that zone and that it is online. Also, I know it might sound redundant, but try specifying the region_name inside of the session creation, so `session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id='*****', aws_secret_access_key='**********', region_name='ca-central-1')`

Comment: You should not need to put any AWS credentials in your code. Instead, you should use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command that can store credentials in a configuration file. It will also ask for the **default region** that will hopefully fix your issue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein:How can this be done if im writing the code in Jupyter notebook?i've tried the following and it still doesn't seem to work                                                                import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
my_config = Config(
    region_name = 'ca-central-1',
   )                                                                                                                     dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb',config=my_config)                                        wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information")

Comment: @Shmack Yes the region is correct and i've tried including the region_name when creating the session object as suggested ,throws the same error

Comment: As per @JohnRotenstein , yes you can download the AWS CLI and follow a simple tutorial to configure it properly. You can then create a session by simply using `session = boto3.Session()`, I believe - something very simple like that. It will read the config file and load your credentials for the session. There are a few select times when you'd want to manually load those sessions, but apart from those, its better practice to configure the CLI and let boto3 handle loading the session. Doing this is nice, because ec2 instances already have this configured and can be loaded the same way as above.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, I want to make 100% clear what I was trying to say: I think you need - `session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id='*****', aws_secret_access_key='**********', region_name='ca'central-1')` - `wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information", boto3_session=session)`.

Comment: To store credentials using the AWS CLI, you would **run it on the command-line** on whatever computer is executing the Jupytr Notebook. Is Jupytr running on your own computer, or an Amazon EC2 instance? Do you have access to the Operating System command line on that computer?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have enough characters or formatting, so I am posting this as an answer so that I can make sure that I convey this properly.

As it stands, this is your code:

```
import awswrangler as wr

from pathlib import Path

session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id='*****', aws_secret_access_key='**********')

dynamodb=session.resource('dynamodb',region_name='ca-central-1')

wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information")
```

I think this is the change that is needed to be made:

```
import awswrangler as wr

from pathlib import Path

# here
session = boto3.Session( aws_access_key_id='*****', aws_secret_access_key='**********', region_name='ca'central-1')

# nothing is done with this
dynamodb=session.resource('dynamodb',region_name='ca-central-1')

# and here
wr.dynamodb.put_df(df=table_program_info_final, table_name="Early_information", boto3_session=session)
```

My assumption - though I don't know for sure - is that you think you have to have a variable called dynamodb. Where wrangler will use it by (for a lack of better words and phrases on my part) magically adding wrangler (`wr`) and the dynamo session resource (`dynamodb`) together by using the syntax (`wr.dynamodb`). Which is not the case. An aside: if I am wrong, my bad, otherwise, maybe we can have a discussion on why that's not the case. You never actually use the `dynamodb` variable for anything that you've given us in your code, so when you go to use `wr.dynamodb.put_df()` it doesn't have a session specified for use, and if you did `wr.dynamodb.put_df(boto3_session=session)` without changing session to be `boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id='id', aws_secret_access_key='key', region_name='the_region')`, then it would make sense as to why it keeps throwing the error, because your initial session doesn't have a region specified. Sorry if I am just completely off on this, but this looks to be my best guess, because that's what the documentation appears to show. An additional note based off of one of your comments: `botocore.config` is used to configure botocore clients (which can actually still be used with boto3 resources - I've used both combined to create s3 presigned urls). Based off my small experience with it, my assumption is that you'd have to pass that config to the client for use - seeing that you don't use a client and that `wrangler.dynamodb.put_df()` doesn't support a config, there is no use for it here. Here is the [docs](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/config.html) for it.